# Limit points of sum of sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I came across a question about proving containment relations between accumulation point sets.

> We define : (A + B) as ${a + b : a \in A, b \in B}$
>   
>  and : acc(A) as the set of accumulation points of A.

Using these, I want to prove:

$(acc(A) + A)\cup(acc(A)+acc(A))\subseteq acc(A+A)$

I've tried using the definition of $acc(A)$ but that didn't work.
Anyone got any hints?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll write $A'$ for the set of accumulation points of a set $A$. Suppose that $x\in A'$ and $a\in A$; we want to show that $x+a\in(A+A)'$. Let $U$ be any open nbhd of $x+a$; then $U-a=\{u-a:u\in U\}$ is an open nbhd of $x$, so $(U-a)\cap A\ne\varnothing$. Let $b\in(U-a)\cap A$; then

$$b+a\in U\cap(A+a)\subseteq U\cap(A+A)\;.$$

$U$ was an arbitrary open nbhd of $x+a$, so $x+a\in(A+A)'$, as desired. This shows that

$$A'+A\subseteq(A+A)'\;.$$

It remains to show that $A'+A'\subseteq(A+A)'$. Let $x,y\in A'$; we want to show that $x+y\in(A+A)'$. There are a couple of ways to approach this. One is similar to what I did above but requires a little preliminary work.

- Let $U$ be any open nbhd of $x+y$. There is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x+y-2\epsilon,x+y+2\epsilon)\subseteq U$. Let $V_x=(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ and $V_y=(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)$, and show that $x+y\in V_x+V_y\subseteq U$. Then use the fact that $V_x\cap A\ne\varnothing\ne V_y\cap A$ to show that $U\cap(A+A)\ne\varnothing$.

The other uses sequences.

- There are sequences $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $A$ converging to $x$ and $y$, respectively. Show that $\langle a_n+b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence in $A+A$ converging to $x+y$.